# is $f(x)= x^7+x-\frac{1}{n}$ injective?

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that $f(x)= x^7+x-\frac{1}{n}$ is injective.

So, if I take two real values $x$ and $y$ and consider the values assumed by the function, they should be the same.

$f(x)=f(y) \rightarrow x^7+x-\frac{1}{n}=y^7+y-\frac{1}{n}\rightarrow x^7+x=y^7+y$
But I don't know how to continue

Comment: Is this a monotone function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use derivatives you were on the right track.

You already had that it had to hold $$x^7+x=y^7+y$$ so let's move forward with this one.
First consider that it follows from above that $x$ and $y$ have to have to same leading sign, wlog let's assume $x,y > 0$ (otherwise we multiply both sides with $(-1)$) and it follows:

$$\begin{align} &&x^7+x&=y^7+y \\ &\iff& (x^7 - y^7) + (x-y) &= 0 \\ &\iff& (x-y)\left(1 + \sum_{k=0}^6 x^ky^{6-k}\right) &= 0 \end{align}$$

but this only holds for $x=y$ because of $$\left(1 + \sum_{k=0}^6 x^ky^{1-k}\right) > 0$$ for $x,y>0$

Answer (score 1):

How about taking the derivative?   $f'(x)=7x^6+1\ne0$.

Thus $f$ is $1-1$.

Comment: @Botond if I want not to use derivatives?